# How do I configure Windows TortoiseGit to auto-export a zip file after I push to remote?

Tags: windows, tortoise-git

I'm developing WordPress plugins. I make edits. I test them. I click sync in the context menu then commit then push.

Now to create the zip file I have to navigate the context menu again then enter the full path for the zip every time.

How do I alter the configuration so that after I push to remote, it automatically creates a zip file with the same name as the folder?

Comment: You can't (to my knowledge) configure tortoise to do that. You could however unleash the power of the commandline and then you can pretty much do anything you want, in particular because you can string operations together as functions in git aliases. But you'd have to get used to the commandline - I don't know how comfortable you are with that.

Comment: I'm comfortable with the command line but I don't want to use it in this case. I want to use the GUI where I right click the folder, choose Tortoise Sync, then type in my messages, click commit, click push, then I want the zip file created for me. If there's a way to alter the context-sensitive menu to do this I'd like that - I looked in registry settings but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: As an extra pointer - TortoiseGit *does* have an 'export' option in the context menu which creates a zip file, which is good because it creates the zip minus the .git folders - but it's a pain because it's buried in the context menu and it doesn't remember the last zip name used.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, you want the push option to "auto-invoke" the export-to-zip option. Well, as TortoiseGit does not allow for that, the only option seems to script your own "batch operation" and insert that in the registry as an operation associated to the relevant file type. You could probably use a simple batch file, or maybe a more elaborate PowerShell script or AutoIt script or something.